# Embedded double quotes work in QT 4.7.4 not in 4.8.6

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Qt 4.7.4 app working. I am trying to update to Qt 4.8.6 however version 4.8.6 doesn't handle embedded double quotes like 4.7.4 has.

As an example the following string is one of twelve that we use as arguments to the QApplication:

```
QString myData = 
    QString("{\"type\":\"IndexFlt\",\"media\":\"1\",\"entityid\":\"0:0:0\"}");
```

In version 4.7.4 the twelve strings passed to QApplication as part of `argv`.

When I get the arguments back via `theApp.arguments()` in version 4.7.4 I get back all arguments with no change in formatting.

However when I pass the same argumetns to version 4.8.6 and then call `theApp.arguments()` the QStringList has only six entries instead of twelve.

When I look at the 6th string I see that QT took arguments 7-12 and added them to first six.

What I see in the debugger for the QStringList of arguments is different between 4.7.4 and 4.8.6. in 4.7.4

I see argument 6 as:

```
"{"type":"IndexFlt","media":"1","entityid":"0:0:0"}"
```

But with version 4.8.6 I see argument 6 as:

```
"{\type":"IndexFlt","media":"1","entityid":"0:0:0"} --ScriptArg:...
```

As you can see instead of a double quote infront of the string `type` I get a `/` and the closing `}` does not get a `"` after it got arguments 7-12 added to argument 6.

Any ideas on how to fix this? The only thing that changed in the application is the version of Qt.

You can use the following code to see the issue with embedded double quotes.
Just make sure that you use at least two arguments with the first argument
containing embedded double quotes. So as an example if the code below was 
compiled to an exe called test.exe then you would envoke test.exe this way:
test.exe --DoubleQuotes="true" -NoDoubleQuotes=false

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtCore/QStringList>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    for (int i=0; i < argc ; i++)
    {
        std::string tmp = argv[i];
        std::cout << tmp << std::endl;
    }

    QApplication theApp(argc, argv);

    QStringList vArgs = theApp.arguments();
    foreach (QString t, vArgs)
    {
        std::cout << t.toStdString() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post a small, single source file program that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I am trying to get more code to display but that may not be allowed. However I have found a much easier way to make this happen. All you need is to have an argv that has embedded double quotes, as an example "--Somthing=\"TRUE\"". When you get that argument back from the QT Application you will see "--Somthing=\TRUE". It appears that 4.8.6 cannot handle embedded double quotes.

Comment: Again: please post a small, single source file program that reproduces the problem.  Otherwise there is too much guesswork involved in trying to reproduce what you're asking about (at least for me).

Comment: Thanks for the sample application - I can reproduce your problem.  I'll try to take a closer look, but can't make any promises about how timely I might be.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are running into stems from a bug in the `argv` parsing that Qt 4.8.6 implments in the template function `qWinCmdLine<>()` (from `qcorecmdlineargs_p.h`).

In Qt 4.7.4, the section of code in that function that handles escaped quotes on the command line looks like (the comments in the left column are my annotations):

```
                    if (*p == '\\') {                // escape char?
/* skip escape */       p++;
                        if (*p == Char('\"') || *p == Char('\''))
/* keep quote */            ;                        // yes
                        else
/* else undo */             p--;                        // treat \ literally
                    } else {
                        if (!quote && (*p == Char('\"') || *p == Char('\''))) {        // " or ' quote
/* note and */              quote = *p++;               
/* skip quote */            continue;
                        } else if (QChar((short)(*p)).isSpace() && !quote)
                            break;
                    }
```

In Qt 4.8.6 that section of the function looks like:

```
                    if (*p == '\\') {                // escape char?
/* BUG */               if (*(p+1) == quote)
                            p++;
                    } else {
                        if (!quote && (*p == Char('\"') || *p == Char('\''))) {        // " or ' quote
                            quote = *p++;
                            continue;
                        } else if (QChar((short)(*p)).isSpace() && !quote)
                            break;
```

The snippets are very similar, except that the 4.8.6 code tries to be a little more clever by skipping the escape character if it sees the next character is a `quote` instead of 4.7.4's technique of skipping the escape char then undoing that action if it notices the next character isn't a `'\"'` or `'\'`. The problem is that at the line I've annotated as `/* BUG */`, the variable `quote` is only set if you're already inside a quoted section.  It doesn't correctly handle an escaped quotation character that isn't in a quoted part of the command line.

Note that sometime between Qt 4.8.6 and Qt 5.3.1, the `qWinCmdLine<>()` function is no longer used on desktop Windows targets (it's only used on WinCE targets). Instead the Win32 API `CommandLineToArgvW()` is used to parse the command line into an `argv` array - and it looks like that brings back the behavior you are looking for (it looks like the bug is fixed in the WinCE-only version of `qWinCmdLine<>()`, too).

So to fix your problem you'll need to use a version of Qt other than 4.8.6 (I'm not sure at what versions the bug crept in or exactly when it was fixed), or you can patch the `qcorecmdlineargs_p.h` file and rebuild Qt if you need 4.8.6 for some reason.

Also note that on Windows, `QCoreApplication` (and therefore `QApplication`) ignores the `argc` and `argv` arguments you pass in. The command line that is parsed is always obtained from the Win32 API `GetCommandLine()`.  While this behavior is documented, it wasn't what I expected and was kind of irritating when I was trying to test things by passing different `argc`/`argv` values to `QCoreApplication` to no effect.

Comment: I know this answer is posted long enough after you asked the question that you might have already moved on to some solution. Still, I hope it's some use to you.